# How to add public access S3 policy on terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform

I am currently trying to add an S3 policy to reflect on my bucket to allow public access through Terraform.

I get the following error when attempting to 'terraform apply'

Error putting S3 policy MalformedPolicy Policy has invalid resource

Attached the following policy due to format issues.

[Terraform Policy Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QWI1v.png)

Comment: Please use properly formatted code blocks for TF code, not screenshots.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are missing the '/' in your resource value. Because if you want to allow for 'get' request to all objects in a bucket you need to do a '/*'. So it should be:

```
Resource = "arn:aws:s3:::dinitestbucket/*"
```